# Turn off webform preview message

Tags: webforms

Before submitting a webform a warning is displayed:

> Here are the details you are about to report.

It appears the default text may be altered in:

*Home > Administration > Structure  > Webforms > Preview settings*

However, can the message be turned off, completely, via the user interface?

Comment: I am assuming your question is for the Webform module for Drupal 8.  You have found a bug/issue because the preview message can't be an empty value.  Please create an issue. https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/webform?version=8.x

Comment: Here is the ticket https://www.drupal.org/node/2917263.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! [Issue #2917263 There is no way of turning off the preview message](https://www.drupal.org/node/2917263)